# Gridview shows only two items android

Tags: android, gridview

// mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:gravity="bottom" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
 </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0.01dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.91"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:onClick="moreEvent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:src="@drawable/book"
            android:onClick="chatNow" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Event Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Venue, Date"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/demo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Event of the Week" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Today&apos;s Events" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

//mainactivity.java

```
class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EventHome.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json = null;
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("All Events: ", json.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try{
            event = new JSONObject(json);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONArray user = event.getJSONArray("events");

        for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = user.getJSONObject(i);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", object.getString("id"));
            map.put("name", object.getString("name"));
            map.put("date_d", object.getString("date_d"));
            map.put("location", object.getString("location"));
            map.put("images", "http://www.example.com/"+object.getString("images"));
            arraylist.add(map);    
        }

        String[] from = {"name", "date_d", "location", "images"};
        int[] to = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3,  R.id.iv_flag};

        ListAdapter adapters = new MyAdapter(EventHome.this,arraylist,R.layout.list_event_home,from,to);
        gv1.setAdapter(adapters);

        gv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+arg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

//MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

   public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
      super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      // here you let SimpleAdapter built the view normally.
      View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      // Then we get reference for Picasso
      ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();
      if(img == null){
         img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
         v.setTag(img); // <<< THIS LINE !!!!
      }
      // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    String url = (String) ((Map)getItem(position)).get("images");
      // do Picasso
      Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).into(img);

      // return the view
      return v;
   }
}
```

while executing the above code my gridview shows only 2 items. Why is it so. Is there any mistake in my xml. Can anyone knows how to fix it. I am stuck in here. Waiting for answers.

Comment: provide some java codes...specially your adapter

Comment: @kgandroid check the question.

Comment: Make sure that the jsonarray user has more than 2 elements and also post your "MyAdapter"

Comment: @kgandroid :- jsonarray user has more than 2 elements. I have added MyAdapter class in question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your gridview contains scroll view so there is a chance to reduce the actual items in your gridview. So try to remove scroll view.